# iOS 7.1 Simulator not downloading

Tags: ios-simulator, osx-yosemite, ios7.1, xcode6.1

I use 
OS X Yosemite 10.10.2, Xcode 6.1.
I want to download iOS 7.1 simulator, but the simulator stuck to download

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a known issue where the DLC download will be pended if you are running on battery.  Please connect to to a power source to continue the download.

Comment: Why on earth isn't there a pop up saying that when you click download! Jesus.

Comment: Because it is a bug.  Newer versions of Xcode are not affected by the bug.

Comment: My saviour! Thank you